# Issue with event positioning fullcalendar angular 7

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar with angular 7 and I have some issue when I tried to display an event with the week or day view. The event is outside the timezone. Have you any idea of how to fix this ?

Image of the result -> https://i.ibb.co/W6vGCMF/Voila-Capture-2019-04-26-03-49-36-PM.png

A sandbox to reproduce the bug (Change the date or go to 26/04/2019)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wq7bea

Answer (score -1):

Well problem solved... I forgot to import stylesheet for timeGridWeek..